# Sql Multi Levels Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this DB diagram:

[image]

Considering the relations in the diagram I want to calculate the sum of LikesCount for each **RoomType** the sum of likes count is to be calculated like that:

```
RoomTypeLikesCount = Sum(Replays.LikesCount) + 
                     Sum(Comments.LikesCount) + 
                     Sum(Posts.LikesCount)
```

According to the relation in the diagram as distinct count.

I wonder if there is any simple high performing way.

[Update]

Note: I want to exclude archived or blocked records and just consider rooms with isVisible = true.

My attempt is:

```
--get comment replays likes, dislikes counts [SUM]
SELECT 
    C.PostID, C.CommentID, 
    ISNULL(COUNT(RP.ReplayID), 0) ReplayCount,
    ISNULL(C.LikesCount, 0) + ISNULL(SUM(RP.LikesCount), 0) LikesCount,
    ISNULL(C.DislikesCount, 0) + ISNULL(SUM(RP.DislikesCount), 0) DislikesCount
INTO 
    #CommentStats
FROM  
    CollaborationDB.DiscussionRooms.Comments C 
LEFT JOIN 
    DiscussionRooms.Replays RP ON RP.CommentID = C.CommentID 
                               AND RP.IsBlocked = 0 
                               AND RP.IsArchived = 0
WHERE 
    c.IsBlocked = 0 
    AND C.IsArchived = 0
GROUP BY 
    C.PostID, C.CommentID, C.LikesCount, C.DislikesCount

--get posts views, likes, dislikes counts 
SELECT 
    P.RoomID, P.PostID, P.ViewsCount,
    ISNULL(COUNT(CS.CommentID), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(ReplayCount), 0) CommentCount,
    ISNULL(P.LikesCount, 0) + ISNULL(SUM(CS.LikesCount), 0) LikesCount,
    ISNULL(P.DislikesCount, 0) + ISNULL(SUM(CS.DislikesCount), 0) DislikesCount
INTO 
    #PostStats
FROM  
    CollaborationDB.DiscussionRooms.Posts P
LEFT JOIN 
    #CommentStats CS ON CS.PostID = P.PostID
                     AND P.IsBlocked = 0 
                     AND P.IsArchived = 0
GROUP BY 
    P.RoomID, P.PostID, P.ViewsCount, P.LikesCount, P.DislikesCount

--get Room Types Rooms, Posts, views, likes, dislikes counts 
SELECT 
    RT.TypeName,
    ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT R.RoomID), 0) [RoomsCount],
    ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT PS.PostID), 0) [PostsCount],
    ISNULL(SUM(PS.LikesCount), 0) LikesCount,
    ISNULL(SUM(PS.DislikesCount), 0) DislikesCount,
    ISNULL(SUM(PS.ViewsCount), 0) ViewsCount
FROM 
    CollaborationDB.DiscussionRooms.RoomTypes RT
LEFT JOIN 
    CollaborationDB.DiscussionRooms.Rooms R ON R.RoomTypeID = RT.RoomTypeID 
                                            AND R.IsVisible = 1 
                                            AND R.IsArchived = 0
LEFT JOIN 
    #PostStats PS ON PS.RoomID = R.RoomID
WHERE 
    rt.IsArchived = 0 
    AND R.IsVisible = 1 
    AND R.IsArchived = 0
GROUP BY 
    RT.RoomTypeID, RT.TypeName
```

Comment: Note-> I want to exclude archived or blocked records and just consider rooms with isVisible = true.

Comment: Also this comment must be in your question instead.

Comment: Too much criticism, with not even one answer.
Was it That Difficult!!!!!!!!!!